# L = {www| w belongs to {0,1}*} prove via pumping lemma

Tags: automata, context-free-language

Is the language given below a CFL? If not prove via Pumping Lemma. 
L = {www| w belongs to {0,1}*}
That much I know that it's not a cfl! But I'm facing difficulty solving it via pumping lemma. Kindly help me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Usage_of_the_lemma  example is related and should be useful.

Comment: This question is better suited to [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) where there are existing answers from previous students you can read. It is not a programming question and does not really belong here.

Comment: At which step of the "pumping lemma proof" are you stuck?